# AngularJS Modularization -- My modules can't be found, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs

My old structure was app/controllers, app/services, app/directives, etc. with all of the controllers in the controllers directory and so on.

Now I am trying to leverage modularization but I'm having troubles. I should've probably done them one by one but now I've done them all without testing any :D

This is my error, repeated the same thing for each module:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.login' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Can someone please explain what I'm missing/misunderstanding/doing wrong?

My current structure is:

```
app 
   login
      login.controller.js
      login.js
      login.html
   signup
      signup.controller.js
      signup.js
      signup.html
   common
      services
         auth.service.js
      filters
      directives
   app.js
```

... and so on.

In app.js, I have:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            // Third Party Plugins
            'ui.router', 'permission', 'satellizer', 'angular-loading-bar',

            // Auth Modules
            'app.login', 'app.signup', 'app.logout', 'app.passwordForgot', 'app.passwordReset'
        ])

        // rest of code....

})();
```

And in all my modules, I have a similar structure. Here is login.js:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.login')
        .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);

    function Config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                data: {
                    permissions: {
                        except: ['isLoggedIn'],
                        redirectTo: 'dashboard.home'
                    }
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController as login'
            });
    }

})();
```

And in my index.blade.php (using Laravel as back end) I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/angular/angular.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/satellizer/satellizer.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/angular-permission/dist/angular-permission.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Common -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/common/services/authService.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Login -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/login/login.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/login/login.controller.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Signup -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/signup/signup.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/signup/signup.controller.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Logout -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/logout/logout.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/logout/logout.controller.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Password Forgot -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/passwordForgot/passwordForgot.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/passwordForgot/passwordForgot.controller.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Password Reset -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/passwordReset/passwordReset.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/passwordReset/passwordReset.controller.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Define angular modules like this `angular.module('app.login', [])`. You are basically getting am injector error so either the definition is wrong or the module object is not found by your rootmodule.

Comment: You're right, I read the docs and have to put an empty array to define it.

Comment: If above does not work then try hard coding the paths for the js files. That is another place which injector will depend on - for adding of module file. Ensure right order - preferable when u are getting errors

Comment: The '[]' did the trick. Straight from the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=app.login -- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the [] in the module method call (in your case you are trying to get the module instead of creating it)

```js
angular
        .module('app.login', [])
        .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?